# Select a string using a Combobox and store in variable to be used after the Tkinter window closes

Tags: python, tkinter, combobox

I have created a simple window for a user to input some string using a `Combobox`.

I have managed to create the drop down list, and a button to close the window, but I am having issues trying to store the selected values in a variable to be used at the next section of the programme.

```
# start programme window
root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Great Britain Basketball')
root.geometry('800x449+300+130')
root.configure(bg='#072462')

#def variable and store based on selection
def comboclick(event):
    select_sheet = cb.get()

#create combobox
cb = ttk.Combobox(root, value=('Mon', 'Tues', 'Wed', 'Thurs'))
cb.current(0)
cb.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', comboclick)
cb.pack()

#set close window button
button_close = Button(root, width=35, text='Close Programme', command=root.quit, 
                      fg='#C51E42', bg='#B4B5B4', borderwidth=1).pack()

root.mainloop()

print(select_sheet)
```

I have tried to define the selection of the combobox (cb) using the .get() but when I tried printing the variable once the programme continues I get the error

```
  print(select_sheet)
NameError: name 'select_sheet' is not defined
```

Comment: The assignment to `select_sheet` in the `comboclikc()` callback function is to a local variable — so you need to declare it `global` there first. Off-topic, but also note that `button_close` will be assigned the value returned from `pack()`, which is always `None`.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback and guidance, makes sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I stated `select_sheed` as a global variable, so it can be modified inside the function, and I have also inserted a start value to `select_sheet`, so if the user doesn't change the value of the combobox, he would still get a value.

Those are the smallests changes that have to be made in order to get it work.

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Great Britain Basketball')
root.geometry('800x449+300+130')
root.configure(bg='#072462')

#def variable and store based on selection
def comboclick(event):
    global select_sheet # Setting select_sheet to global, so it can be modified
    select_sheet = cb.get()

# I am setting here the same value of cb.current(), so if the user doesn't change it, you still get an output.
select_sheet = 'Mon'

#create combobox
cb = ttk.Combobox(root, value=('Mon', 'Tues', 'Wed', 'Thurs'))
cb.current(0)
cb.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', comboclick)
cb.pack()

#set close window button
button_close = tk.Button(root, width=35, text='Close Programme', command=root.quit, 
                      fg='#C51E42', bg='#B4B5B4', borderwidth=1).pack()

root.mainloop()

print(select_sheet)
```

Comment: Thank you Eric, Been staring at it for ages but the changes have done the job! Appreciate the explanation as makes more sense moving forward